# python subprocess reading terminal output and reply using PyQt4 message pop up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

Hi im making a program to check adb devices in python

I cant make a pop up window please correct my code.

import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

ad = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "devices"])

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))


        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Check Device', checkadb(ad))
        btn.resize(135, 30)
        btn.move(50, 10)

        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

def clicked(*args):
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(QtGui, "No Device Found")

def clicked2(*args):
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(QtGui, "Device Found")

def checkadb(ad):
    if len(ad) <= 27:
        clicked()

elif len(ad) > 27:
    clicked2()

def main():

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Showing us some of the context (i.e. more code) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be looking for [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)? Your use of `subprocess.call()` will give you the return code of the command executed (a `0` indicates normal exit status).

If your result was in fact the string `"List of devices attached\n\n0"` then you should use `.splitlines()` to split the string by each line into a list, which would be `["List of devices attached", "", "0"]`. This would be in the case that despite what I am lead to believe by the code in your question, you are returning the correct result, i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context might help; are you having trouble getting the output into your code? If so, you might consider using subprocess.Popen(...) instead. It takes a list of arguments, and can easily get output from a specified source. For example, if you wanted to run 'ls myDir', you could use:

```
adbCmd = subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'devices'], stdout=PIPE)
```

Then you can use the Popen object's communicate() method to ensure the command runs to completion and get stdout and stderr:

```
adbOut, adbErr = adbCmd.communicate()
```

Or, since communicate returns a tuple, if you only want stdout:

```
adbOut = adbCmd.communicate()[0]
```

Then you can parse normally to find the number you want.