# Open window when process runs. PYQT

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am newbie in PyQt and coding GUI. I try to automate an other software with subprocess commands. I have button to run command. The process has many loop inside, and I want to display if loop finished and successful or not. Everythings work, but my problem is while i push the button, the second window open after the process is finish. I try to deals with `QtGui.Qapplication.processEvent()`, but I don't really know where to place it. I simplify the problem with using an iterative loop.

```
import sys, os, subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import externalCommands as run
import QtObject as QO
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))

# Don't write .pyc file
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

class OtherWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, working_folder):
        super(OtherWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 640, 528)
        self.setWindowTitle('Autre Fenetre ')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('mc3icon.jpg'))
        self.working_folder = working_folder

        #---home display---
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        QO.button('Abort', 530, 490, 'default', 'default', self.abort_calculation, self)

        for tc in range(len(self.working_folder)):
            currentWorkingFolder = os.path.abspath('../../workingfolder/' + self.working_folder[tc])
            os.chdir(currentWorkingFolder)

            QO.label('Running ' + str(self.working_folder[tc] ), 50, 0 + 50 * tc, self)
            source = run.checked_paramter_files('ms*', '*.exe')

            if (len(source) == 0):
                QO.label('***ERROR*** File *dcp, *.dat, *.exe not found', 250, 0 + 50 * tc, self)
                QO.picture("unchecked.png", 590, 12.5 + 50*tc, 30, 25, self)
            else:
                command = ('./program.exe descriptionFile.dcp')
                p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                    print line,
                QO.picture("checked.png", 590, 12.5 + 50*tc, 25, 25, self)

    def abort_calculation(self):
         #---pop message box---
         choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Abort', 'Are you sure you to stop? \n Calculation will abort', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
           self.close()
        else:
            pass


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1024, 768)
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI test ')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image.jpg'))

        image = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        image.setGeometry(390, 25, 800, 260)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('image.png')
        image.setPixmap(pixmap)
        image.show()

        self.working_folder = os.listdir(os.path.abspath('../../workingfolder/.'))

        #---bar menu---
        extractAction = QtGui.QAction('&Quit', self)
        extractAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        extractAction.setStatusTip('leave the app')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        optionMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Options')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

        self.labelWarning = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.labelWarning.setText('***WARNING***')
        self.labelWarning.setStyleSheet('color: red')
        self.labelWarning.move(420, 100)
        self.labelWarning.resize(600, 600)

        #---home display---
        self.home()


    def home(self):

        #---button : quit ---
        QO.button('Quit', 910, 710, 'default', 'default', self.close_application, self)

        #---button : run fortran sofware ---
        QO.button('Run ', 570, 450, 'default', 'default', self.open_new_window, self)

        #---tree widget : list available folders to run fortran software---
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 75, 380, 650))
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabel('Available Test Cases')

        for i in xrange(len(self.working_folder)):
            parent = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
            parent.setText(0, str(self.working_folder[i]))
            parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            tmp_list_files = os.listdir(os.path.abspath('../../workingfolder/' + self.working_folder[i] + "/."))
            for x in xrange(len(tmp_list_files)):
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
                child.setFlags(child.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                 child.setText(0, tmp_list_files[x])
                 child.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

        #---show---
        self.show()


    def close_application(self):
        #---pop message box---
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are you sure you to quit?', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Program closed sucessfully')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


    def open_new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = OtherWindow(self.working_folder)
        self.newWindow.show()


def main():
    app    = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)
    GUI    = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: 2nd window of what? the process window that you run the launched exe in?

Comment: I have a main window, and i am supposed to open new window when i click on "run". Then, a window open and for each loop in process display a message. But when i click on "run", process run correctly, but window doesn't open in same time. The window opens after loop is finished.  Is it more clear? 
thank

Comment: so in other words, your spawning of the process is not really independent and still blocks the main gui loop. The process that you are talking about is an .exe I suppose (btw you have not mentioned which OS you're on), at least on windows you can launch these new processes in a way where it waits for it to complete, or it's your choise of spawning in Qt or the cofig of it. How it works when doing it with Qt I don't know. Everytime I have come across these things it's a lot of trial and error together with reading, and most of the time it ends up working. I can't really help more than that.

Comment: I work on Linux (Fedora version). Maybe you don't understand what i am doing. When you are on linux your can run .exe on terminal. With subprocess command from python i replace terminal to execute my software in python.  This is my "run" button. But when i click on it, i want to open a window and on same time execute .exe. These two things run, but not in the same time, subprocess freeze GUI and i have to wait until the end that the python open the window. Do you understand better? Thank again for your help

Comment: I do understand your problem, which I have had similar myself that I have managed to work around by experimenting with settings to the subprocess calls and a lot of documentation reading. As said I can't help more than that. Have you looked at other answers related to Linux/PyQT/QtThreads/QtRunnable. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325630/python-subprocess-reading-terminal-output-and-reply-using-pyqt4-message-pop-up) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843876/using-qthreadpool-with-qrunnable-in-pyqt4).

Comment: also when you paste code it's easier for others to focus on the issue at hand if you only provide a minimal example, not the complete thing with lot's of unrelated pieces of code. Looking at your code I cannot find any use of python subprocess/thread or QtRunnable/QtThreads, so I do not understand why you expect it to run independently, when you have not asked the computer to run it independently.

Comment: I thought i was clear, excuse me. OK start again, i post code with the subprocess. I read multiple answered about QtThreat/PyQt... but i had to say i didn't really understand how to use thread. I think my problem is simple. If you look in the second class, i execute, in my second window, a loop which will execute the subprocess. and at each loop i print in the window a message will icon.

Comment: The only thing, is that this second window opens after the loop is finished. I want to open window, execute loop that all. I edit 'class OtherWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):' . As i said before, i tried to use QtGui.Qapplication.processEvent() without sucess.

Thank your time.

Comment: when you have a gui-app, that app is blocking and needs to be blocking (how could it otherwise read keystrokes, mouse movements etc), it of course has event handling, signal/slot in Qt. As said I can't help much apart from pointing out what way I believe you need to go. It's probably not a good idea to use the built-in python subprocess framework, you should use the PyQt built-in framework to make your subprocess with, and you also need to make it as an independent process outside of the gui-loop. There are examples around for `QtRunnable/QtThreadPool` which will do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank, i will read this careful.